# Check if one of my select tag as change with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have few select withs the same class, I want to manipulate the changed select.

I tried:

```
  $(".test_suite").change(function (event) {

    val =  $(this).val()
  });
```

but the this work only on the first select.

maybe each will resolved the issue?

any assist will help :)

thanks,
Cfir.

Comment: could you provide sample code on jsfeddle?

Comment: Can you show more code? html

Comment: Have any code or JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wy907kbp/4/

```
$('.test_suite').on('change', function (event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

You said that want to modify selected value, which you need to explain more.

Comment: the first select wrote on the html but the others are dynamically produce in .js and the change event is perform on other .js. it may effect it?

Comment: So you are craeting `<select>` elements on fly. Than you need to learn about `on()` event handler http://api.jquery.com/on/ , check my edited code

Comment: @cfircoo I've updated fiddle to confirm it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/wy907kbp/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test_suite").change(function (event) {
  val =  $(event.target).val()
});
```